# Why cant I set this pointer to NULL?

Tags: c, pointers, structure

I'm having some problems setting a pointer within a structure to NULL. I'm getting a segimtation fault. What is causing this and how can I fix it?

```
typedef struct data_{
  void *data;
  struct data_ *next;
}data_el;

typedef struct buckets_{
  char *key;
  data_el *head_data_p;
}buckets;

typedef struct hash_table_ {
  /* structure definition goes here */
  int (*hash_func)(char *);
  int (*comp_func)(void*, void*);
  buckets **buckets_array;
} hash_table, *Phash_table;

int i,size;
size = 10;

table_p -> buckets_array = (buckets **)malloc(sizeof(buckets)*(size+1));

for(i = 0; i < size; i++){
/*Getting segmitation falut here*/
table_p -> buckets_array[i] -> key = NULL;
table_p -> buckets_array[i] -> head_data_p = NULL;
```

Comment: 1. What is `table_p`? 2. Don't cast return value of `malloc` 3. You're putting a single-dimensional array in a pointer that should hold a two-dimensional array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you aren't initializing `buckets_array`. So the pointers don't yet point to anything and you get an error when you try and modify what they point to.

You need to initialize your array of pointers, and also each individual pointer:

```
table_p -> buckets_array = malloc(sizeof(buckets *) * (size+1));

for(i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    table_p -> buckets_array[i] = malloc(sizeof(bucket));
    table_p -> buckets_array[i] -> key = NULL;
    table_p -> buckets_array[i] -> head_data_p = NULL;
}
```

Comment: Also I think he's dereferencing `table_p` without it pointing to anything, you might add that to the example.

Comment: @Seth, right you are, but the OP doesn't even show the declaration for `table_p`. I don't even know what type it is.

Comment: He did in a comment on the question which didn't include `= malloc...` which is why I think he didn't initialise it.

Answer (score 1):

You should replace:

```
buckets **buckets_array;
```

With:

```
buckets *buckets_array;
```

And:

```
(buckets **)malloc(sizeof(buckets)*(size+1));
```

With:

```
(buckets *)malloc(sizeof(buckets)*(size+1));
```

And also:

```
table_p -> buckets_array[i] -> key = NULL;
table_p -> buckets_array[i] -> head_data_p = NULL;
```

With:

```
table_p -> buckets_array[i] . key = NULL;
table_p -> buckets_array[i] . head_data_p = NULL;
```

Comment: You should remove the cast from `malloc`